# Don't know how to restrict inner SQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xmlwriter

Tons of S/O searching has been extremely helpful so far ... and the following *almost* works. My problem is the second SQL query returns ALL the 'ingredients' for EACH 'recipe' -- whereas Recipe #1 has ingredients A,C,F, and Recipe #2 had ingredients A,G,H. How do I restrict the second query to return only the ingredients for the recipe in the current loop? I'd be very grateful for a PHP/SQL wizard's help to get over the top.

DB structure with many-to-many relationship:

```html
RECIPE (recid, title) 
REC_ING (recid, ingid) 
INGREDIENT (ingid, ingredient)
```

Here's my PHP code:

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "recipe";
try {
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$xml = new XMLWriter();
$xml->openURI('stackexch.xml');
$xml->setIndent(2);
$xml->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->startElement('recipes');
$recipe = $db->query("SELECT * FROM recipe");
foreach ($recipe as $row) {
  $xml->startElement('recipe');
  $xml->startElement('title');
  $xml->writeRaw($row['title']);
  $xml->endElement();
  $ingredient = $db->query("SELECT ingredient FROM recipe, rec_ing, ingredient WHERE recipe.recid=rec_ing.recid AND ingredient.ingid=rec_ing.ingid");
  foreach ($ingredient as $subrow) {
    $xml->startElement('ingredient');
    $xml->writeRaw($subrow['ingredient']);
    $xml->endElement();
    }
  $xml->endElement();
}
$xml->endElement();
$xml->endDocument();
$xml->flush();
?>
```

And here's what is returned:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<recipes>
  <recipe>
    <title>Recipe #1</title>
    <ingredient>ingredient A</ingredient>
    <ingredient>ingredient C</ingredient>
    <ingredient>ingredient F</ingredient>
    <ingredient>ingredient G</ingredient>
    <ingredient>ingredient H</ingredient>
  </recipe>
  <recipe>
    <title>Recipe #2</title>
    <ingredient>ingredient A</ingredient>
    <ingredient>ingredient C</ingredient>
    <ingredient>ingredient F</ingredient>
    <ingredient>ingredient G</ingredient>
    <ingredient>ingredient H</ingredient>
  </recipe>
</recipes>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming recid is the id of the recipe.
Try this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "recipe";
try {
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$xml = new XMLWriter();
$xml->openURI('stackexch.xml');
$xml->setIndent(2);
$xml->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->startElement('recipes');
$recipe = $db->query("SELECT * FROM recipe");
foreach ($recipe as $row) {
  $xml->startElement('recipe');
  $xml->startElement('title');
  $xml->writeRaw($row['title']);
  $xml->endElement();
  $ingredient = $db->query("SELECT ingredient FROM recipe, rec_ing, ingredient WHERE recipe.recid=rec_ing.recid AND ingredient.ingid=rec_ing.ingid AND recipe.recid = " . $row['recid']);
  foreach ($ingredient as $subrow) {
    $xml->startElement('ingredient');
    $xml->writeRaw($subrow['ingredient']);
    $xml->endElement();
    }
  $xml->endElement();
}
$xml->endElement();
$xml->endDocument();
$xml->flush();
?>
```

Since you're already selecting from the recipe table, you don't need to select from it again.
You could probably simplify the code like this:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "recipe";
    try {
      $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
       echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $xml = new XMLWriter();
    $xml->openURI('stackexch.xml');
    $xml->setIndent(2);
    $xml->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $xml->startElement('recipes');
    $recipe = $db->query("SELECT * FROM recipe");
    foreach ($recipe as $row) {
      $xml->startElement('recipe');
      $xml->startElement('title');
      $xml->writeRaw($row['title']);
      $xml->endElement();
      $ingredient = $db->query("SELECT ingredient FROM rec_ing, ingredient WHERE ingredient.ingid=rec_ing.ingid AND rec_ing.recid = " . $row['recid']);
      foreach ($ingredient as $subrow) {
        $xml->startElement('ingredient');
        $xml->writeRaw($subrow['ingredient']);
        $xml->endElement();
        }
      $xml->endElement();
    }
    $xml->endElement();
    $xml->endDocument();
    $xml->flush();
    ?>
```

Typically, I wouldn't recommend concatenating variables into a query, but in this case it is safe because you're already selecting the id from the database.

Comment: Jonhasacat, you are my hero for today. Simple and brilliant solution. Danke.

Answer (score 0):

This is consuming resources:

```
SELECT * FROM recipe
```

Yet you use only [title], so why pull all columns?

This is being executed for each row returned from above:

```
SELECT ingredient 
FROM recipe, rec_ing, ingredient 
WHERE recipe.recid=rec_ing.recid AND ingredient.ingid=rec_ing.ingid
```

But you can do both of the above in one query, therefore consuming less resources:

```
SELECT r.title, i.ingredient 
FROM recipe r
INNER JOIN rec_ing ON r.recid=rec_ing.recid 
INNER JOIN ingredient i ON i.ingid=rec_ing.ingid
```

Also note, over 25 years ago ANSI formalized a set of joins that you should try to adopt. 2 tips for this:

1. deny yourself the use of commas between tables names in the from clause, and
2. if a condition has two table references, this condition belongs to a JOIN e.g **recipe**.recid=**rec_ing**.recid (see? that has a table reference on each side of the equals, this is a join condition)

One last suggestion: a SQL query does not have to be a single row in PHP code.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for these great tips. I'll play, learn, and report back tomorrow. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. 
You would need to add the 
`RECIPE.recid='.$row['recid']` in the where clause.

However from my perspective you can simplify the logic using only one query. I would suggest to use inner joins to include the information from multiple tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM recipe AS r
INNER JOIN rec_ing AS ri ON ri.recid=r.recid
INNER JOIN INGREDIENT AS i ON i.ingid=ri.ingid;
```

Comment: Thank you Emilio! My SQL is rusty, but this looks great. I will try it tomorrow and report back (or ask for more clarification). Much appreciated. I'm a new member but I've been a lurker for awhile - this is an amazing community and I hope to pay it forward.